# how to access X server and executing graphic programs remotely?

Tags: linux

I have a X server on pc1 which I access through ssh -X from pc2. I know I can run graphic applications on pc1 and display the applicaction's window on pc2, but is it possible to also display the window on pc1 like VNC does?

Moreover, how can i access X server remotely without using ssh? I heard that it can be dangerous to enable access to all users in Xhost since they might even catch keystrokes, how come? Isn't it just a X server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To gain access to a full Linux GUI session remotely, see [FreeNX](http://freenx.berlios.de)